# Prevent divs from colliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a game where users can chat. Every speech is appended to body as position `absolute` element with `user x position` as "left" CSS tag. They are also animated to go to top. I don't want them to have a colliding, vertically or horisontally. 
Here's an example: 
[image]

They don't have to be one on another, but they need to be `"one after one"`

I have tried a `jquery each()` and then remove 60 pixel from the current speech position. Here's my code:

```
var Speech = {
    History: [],
    New: function(user, text, int) {
        var pos = getUserPosition(user).x + 18;
        var speech = HTML.Speech.split('\n');
        var maxInt = speech.length - 1;
        if (int <= maxInt) {
            var html   = speech[int];
            var random = Rand(10);

            Speech.pushThemUp();

            /** append here ect...
            set left position...
            $('#speech' + random).css("left", nLeft + "px"); **/
        }
    },
    pushThemUp: function() {
        $('.speech').each(function(i, obj) {
            var newTop = parseInt($(this).css('top')) - 60;
            $(this).css('top', newTop+'px');
        });
    },
    Listener: function() {
        var int = setInterval(function() {
            $('.speech').each(function(i, obj) {
                if(parseInt($(this).css('top')) < 0) {
                    $(this).remove();
                } else {
                    var newTop = parseInt($(this).css('top')) - 10;
                    $(this).animate({'top': newTop+'px'});
                }
            });
         }, 1000);
    },
    getHistory: function() {
        return Speech.History;
    }
};
Speech.Listener();
module.exports = Speech;
```

But it doesn't work. They can still have colliding like the example up.

How can I solve that?

Please note: in that example, `Speech.Listener()` wasn't called.

**EDIT: finally, I think my current solution to loop over .speech class and then add top px is good, but why is it animated? Look at the gif, pushThemUp function don't have to animate the speech bubbles but directly edit position, how can I solve that?**

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what you define as a 'colission'

Comment: I want to say `colliding`, one don't need to touch another

Comment: I mean how do you define a `colliding`, what behavior do you associate with a `colliding`. You say you don't mind them being on top of eachother, though to me that sounds like a `colliding`, which you say you want to prevent from happening.

Comment: Why don't you use `position:relative`? That would bypass the problem and would be much easier!

Comment: Or, you can get the offset and height of last speech bubble and set the offset of new speech bubble accordingly e.g. adding 10px to last bubble's offset + its height.

Comment: @Glubus I mind them being on top of eachother, that's what I don't want and what I want to prevent

Comment: @Aloso here's the result... http://prntscr.com/azt3am

Comment: post edited, check it please

Answer (score 0):

I created a code snippet where messages appear and move upwards. When there's no space left, a scrollbar appears.

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var topp = 3;

function post(str) {
  var obj = document.createElement("div");
  obj.className = "chatObj";
  obj.innerHTML = str;
  box.appendChild(obj);
  box.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

  var width = obj.clientWidth;
  var height = obj.clientHeight;
  obj.style.marginLeft = (box.clientWidth / 2 - width / 2) + "px";

  var x = 15;
  obj.style.top = (box.clientHeight - x - height) + "px";

  var interval, ctop;
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    x += 4;
    console.log(ctop, topp);
    ctop = box.clientHeight - x - height;
    obj.style.top = ctop + "px";
    if (ctop <= topp) {
      obj.style.top = topp + "px";
      topp += height + 6;
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 5);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  post("Hi!");
}, 500);

setTimeout(function() {
  post("Trollolo!");
}, 1500);

setTimeout(function() {
  post("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, timeam aliquando ei cum, putent possim in usu, at causae pericula petentium has. In mea legere salutatus voluptaria. No vix ancillae accusata. Nec meis probo noster eu, ius no quas audire.<br><br>Qui quem nominavi ei. Pri nisl eirmod id. Has cetero vocent abhorreant no, at mei altera expetendis. Has id novum aeterno salutatus.<br><br>Prompta offendit et eos, eos an admodum comprehensam, ex velit doming dolorem mei. At has dolor alterum laoreet, id duo tollit libris contentiones. An mel recteque omittantur dissentiet, ex nam novum iuvaret. Per id alterum habemus gubergren.<br><br>Nulla possim mea in. Vis et postulant constituam. Viris vulputate vituperatoribus eu usu, wisi meis ex his. Prompta accumsan cum et, possim eligendi omittantur sed id. Eos ad nemore integre recusabo, agam doctus viderer ei pri, cu eius nonumes senserit vis. Qui iudico causae te.<br><br>Eam ne mandamus evertitur, case adversarium neglegentur duo ex, no cum nominati forensibus. Et vel putant deleniti. Illum aliquando voluptatibus per no, ei quo albucius phaedrum. Cu lorem appetere percipit sed, ubique epicuri ad eos, te eos diam nusquam persecuti. Eu qui meis illum eleifend, eam veniam vivendo no, nisl fierent in quo.");
}, 2500);
```

```css
#box {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
  overflow: auto;
}
#box .chatObj {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#box .chatObj::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: ".";
  color: transparent;
  height: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `position: relative` and a wrapper element with `display: block`, you can get exactly what you want without having to worry about collision detection. The only thing you'll need to do is calculate the initial `top` value based on the players position minus the initial top position of the bubble (since using `position: relative` the bubbles will be added to the DOM bellow the last bubble).

See this simple jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/straker/0n6jbupg/

Comment: Please note that there's a <canvas clickable element, so I can't add a div with display block, width & height at 100% and z-index superior than canvas one, because the canvas will not became clickable. If I need width 100% it's because it depends of the user x position

Comment: You could stack the canvas and the text boxes behind a div/other canvas that takes up the same width/height, then use that for your click calculations. So order of top to bottom would be: clicking element, text boxes, canvas.